# MultipartEntity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, apache

Trying to use MultipartEntity in my android application, but i dont have such class.
What's problem? 
Eclipse error :

> MultipartEntity cannot be resolved to a type

```
Android Developer Tools
```

Build: v22.3.0-887826

How to fix it?

Comment: When you used a search engine and searched on `android multipartentity`, what did you learn?