# Send an image to a server using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have to send an image to a server (I think the best option is using HttpURLConnection) and recieve from it a String answer. In the different docuemnts and web sites that I have read, I have investigated that the best way to do this is using MultipartEntity.

1_ Is it the best solution to do it?

2_ I had an error which says that Android Studio cannot resolve the symbol 'MultipartEntity'. I read that to solve it I have to download external libraries. Which are them and how can I download them?

3_ For this I want to run this process in backGround, but I have a mistake writing the AsyncTask like `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` because I want to recieve the parameters like in the answer from this question ([Sending files using POST with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection)): `String urlString, MultipartEntity reqEntity`. How can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Use Gradle to get libraries. Okhttp can handle sending files. You're probably seeing Apache HTTP which doesn't exist in Android anymore (by default)

Comment: If you want to use that class, see here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470486/android-multipartentity-and-dependencies

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't resolve it using the default libraries and I read here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240376/multipartentity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type] that I can only solve it using external libraries. And there is a link which takes you to gitHub and appears a message number 404

Comment: All of them? Apache HTTP components & mime are what you're looking for, I assume

Comment: @cricket_007 that page says that the library's name is 'httpmime:4.4'. Does it mean that I can only use it from KitKat? Because I'm trying to do an application which you can run from GingerBread. And ignore my prrevious question. I deleted it

Comment: 4.4 is the Apache library version. Unrelated to your Android version

Comment: Oh, perfect. I will try to do it

Comment: @cricket_007 I did it and I have 2 dependencies: one is from apache and the other one is from lucee. I have to download only apache's one, don't I?

Comment: Lucene? That shouldn't be needed

Comment: nono. It's lucee. If you want to watch it, I can edit the publication sending a screenshot. But for everybody says I think that the once that I am looking for is Apache haha

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to download yourself. You just edit the gradle file, that's it

Comment: I downloaded the apache dependency and it worked: I write `MultipartEntityBuilder req;` and it says it is okay

Comment: @cricket_007 He's trying to download the apache http libraries.  They support multipart forms, whereas HttpUrlConnection, while a better library, do not.  If you need to do multipart, you need to program it in yourself or use the old DefaultHttpClient, which requires grabbing it as a dependency.  Practically speaking its easier to use Apache than do it yourself.

Comment: @GabeSechan I am aware... Did you think I was steering him wrong? I said to use Gradle to download, not a JAR file. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the best option is using HttpURLConnection
>
> Is it the best solution to do it?

Probably not. It's too low-level for multi-part requests.

> I had an error which says that Android Studio cannot resolve the symbol 'MultipartEntity'. I read that to solve it I have to download external libraries. Which are them and how can I download them?

Options include, but not limited to

- Apache HTTP (which is where MultipartEntity comes from)
- [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) with a [multipart example](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostMultipart.java)
- [VolleyPlus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus)

You can get either using Gradle. For Apache see: [Android - MultipartEntity and dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470486/android-multipartentity-and-dependencies), and Okhttp just read their documentation where it says "Gradle"

> For this I want to run this process in Background

Can't remember about Apache, but OkHttp already can handle that without an AsyncTask.